# Check: does table exist in SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, information-schema, advanced-installer

I have an installation script containing the following:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'mydatabasename' 
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA  = 'dbo' 
      AND TABLE_NAME    = 'sometablename' 
      AND TABLE_TYPE    = 'BASE TABLE'
)
CREATE TABLE dbo.sometablename ...
```

Problem is that

- I have to allow the user to select a different database name
- I cannot use any placeholders ("variables") in the script.
- the database server may of course contain a different database which already contains a table `sometablename`

The installer does a `USE mydatabasename` before the script is executed; and the installer allows to select a variable database name for this. However, I can't use that variable inside the script, because every replacement in the SQL script is already done at build time of the installer.

So, how can I check whether the used database already contains table `sometablename`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `TABLE_CATALOG` from your query.  All tables in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` view belong to the current database.

Answer (score 0):

You may select the name of the actual database in use and replace it in an execute statement.

```
declare @dbname varchar(50) -- Adjust to your longer database name length.

set     @dbname = db_name()

if not exists (
    select 1
        from information_schema.tables
        where table_catalog  = @dbname
            and table_schema = 'dbo'
            and table_name   = 'someTableName'
            and table_type   = 'base table'
) begin
    execute (
        'create table ' + @dbname + '.dbo.someTableName (
            someFieldName someDataType
            ...
        )'
    )
end
```

Otherwise, it always uses the current database so that it considers the database currently in used selected through your `use` statement.

[**SQL SERVER – Get Current Database Name**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/12/sql-server-get-current-database-name/)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the [SQL Script replacement support from Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/sql-script-replace.html).

Indeed, the replacement is done at build time, but the properties referenced are resolved at **install time**, so you can use the database name selected by the user. Just set the field "Replace with" correctly: **[SELECTED_DB]**

The replacement in the script is done at build time because you cannot write directly the properties as formatted in the script (syntax restrictions).